Minimizing mesh deformation
How would I prevent the mesh from deformating this badly when moving bones or at least minimize it?


You will need to be a bit more clear about what you mean by "deforming this badly". Show what you have, what you're aiming for, clear examples of what the problem is, what you've already tried. Share your blend file if possible.  Instructions for sharing.
